# React conditional components mount multiple times

Tags: reactjs

I'm not using react router and simply have some condition to show and hide certain components.

```
  return (<div className={classes.content}>
     { Navigation[this.state.view] && Navigation[this.state.view].selected === 'colors' && <Colors /> }
     { Navigation[this.state.view] && Navigation[this.state.view].selected === 'typography' && <Typography /> }
     { Navigation[this.state.view] && Navigation[this.state.view].selected === 'decoration' && <Decoration /> }
     { Navigation[this.state.view] && Navigation[this.state.view].selected === 'footer' && <Footer /> }
</div>)
```

This will call componentDidMount inside each component with the number of times that those conditions are met. Can you pinpoint what's wrong with the way I'm showing and hiding the components.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve your problem could be to store the map to your pages in your class or in any variable outside of your render. The component will need to be wrapped into functions to not be mounted when initializing your variable.

This can be done in your constructor for example :

```
this.pages = {
    colors: () => <Colors/>,
    typography: () => <Typography/>,
    decoration: () => <Decoration/>,
    footer: () => <Footer/>
}
```

Now, in your render, just take out the navigation page name you wish to load, extract the right one from your JSON object and call the function to render the correct element without loading the others :

```
const nav = Navigation[this.state.view]

return (
    <div className={classes.content}>
        {nav && this.pages[nav.selected]()}
    </div>
)
```

Comment: You could also do `this.pages = {Colors, Typography, ...}` and call `React.createElement` directly: `{nav && React.createElement(this.pages[nav.selected])}`.

Comment: This is another possibility, although using `React.createElement` is a little clunky. Feel free to post your own answer if you have a different solution

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of that you are creating a react element every time those conditions are met. So I believe you can fix that by creating those components once, and returning them as needed.

So you need something like this:

```
class Something extends Component {
    constructor() {
        this.pages = {
            colors: <Colors />,
            typography: <Typography />
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={classes.content}>
                { Navigation[this.state.view] && Navigation[this.state.view].selected === 'colors' && this.pages.colors }
                { Navigation[this.state.view] && Navigation[this.state.view].selected === 'typography' && this.pages.typography }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

(You can also implement some lazy-loading behavior to createElements as needed and returning the previously created one if is available)